# Change the behaviour of the markdown renderer?

Tags: r, markdown

By default, the `markdown` package renders an image like this

```
> library(markdown)
> txt <- "![my caption](/img/my_image.png)"
> res <- renderMarkdown(text=txt); res
[1] "<p><img src=\"/img/my_image.png\" alt=\"my caption\"/></p>\n"
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to change this default behaviour and put in my own renderer for certain tags/elements. For instance, I may want to use "my caption" not only as `alt` attribute, but also as text below the image.

Is this possible, and is there an example that I can study to figure this out?

Comment: Have you tried package "knitr" ? It can render markdown + R code (in the same file). And with option fig.cap='my caption' I always get text below the image.

Comment: That is an option, I am yet trying to avoid `pandoc`, maybe I should not.

Comment: Or simply add some JavaScript to your HTML file that will do the transformations on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using MultiMarkdown

```
$ cat test.txt 
![my caption](/img/my_image.png)

$ multimarkdown test.txt
<figure>
<img src="/img/my_image.png" alt="my caption" />
<figcaption>my caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

It goes outside R, but it should be easy writing a wrapper of some kind. Also it is fast and supports many other things. I like it better than pandoc personally. It also supports referencing figures: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/MxGKvnNI08c